# NestJS: Using forRoot / forChild in custom module - race condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

[Repo](https://github.com/appsolutegeek/race-condition-nest) is available here to highlight the issue.

I am having a problem with a race condition. I have created a `ConfigModule` - this has a `forRoot` and a `forChild`.

The `forRoot` sets up the loading of the `.env` file and the `forChild` uses it in another module.

The problem is that `forChild` is called before `forRoot`. The `ConfigService` would be injected with missing config because `forRoot` hasn't executed first.

```
> AppModule > ConfigModule.forRoot InstanceModule >
> ConfigModule.forChild
```

I placed some simple `console.log` commands that output this

```
I am in Config Module  FOR CHILD
I am in Config Module  FOR ROOT
```

As you can see the `forChild` is being executed first, I tried using `forwardRef` and that didn't work.

If you let the application run you will see

```
[2019-03-24T11:49:33.602] [ERROR] ConfigService - There are missing mandatory configuration: Missing PORT
[2019-03-24T11:49:33.602] [FATAL] ConfigService - Missing mandatory configuration, cannot continue!, exiting
```

This is because I check that some `process.env` are available which are loaded in via `dotenv`. Of course, because the `forRoot` isn't executed first then the `forChild` returns its own new instance of the `ConfigService`.

`ConfigService` validates the availability of the environment variables.

So, basically, the `forChild` is executing and returning its own `ConfigService` before `forRoot`.

TO make it work, if you comment out the `InstanceModule` inside the `AppModule` then it will automatically start listening and returns the port number from an environment variable.

Of course, because `InstanceModule` uses the `forChild` - there is a race condition.

Comment: Can you post the link to your repo?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I forgot to paste it :-) Updated it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Why does this not work?

1) Nest builds up a dependency graph and instantiates the given modules and their providers according to this graph. The order of your imports or the naming of your dynamic modules's methods (`forRoot`/`forChild`) does not influence the order of the instantiation.

2) When you create dynamic modules, each module will be its own instance, they won't be singletons like regular modules. In your case, you'd create two different `ConfigModule` instances and with it, two different `ConfigService` instances; hence they won't share your `.env` configuration. This can't work, independent of the instantiation order.

---

### Alternatives

Have a look at the `nestjs/typeorm` package. Under the hood, it creates a shared [`TypeOrmCoreModule`](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/blob/e3e60b5683917041575c57d4684b9acb8ca63be8/lib/typeorm-core.module.ts#L32), which is shared between the different dynamic module instances created by `TypeOrmModule.forRoot` / `TypeOrmModule.forChild`. For it to be shared and dynamic at the same time, it has to be made `@Global` though. In your case, since you don't have any configurations in your `forChild` imports, you would just make the whole `ConfigModule` global and then omit the `forChild()` imports, since the `ConfigService` would be globally available anyway.

If you don't want your service to be globally available, you could initialize your service after the startup process, for example in your `AppModule`'s `onModuleInit` method.

Comment: Great explanation, I tested it and it works. And Thanks for explaining the forRoot and forChild - its now much more clearer.